# react-hook-form: How validate object works

Tags: react-hook-form

I see in the docs

```js
<input
  {...register("test1", {
    validate: {
      positive: v => parseInt(v) > 0,
      lessThanTen: v => parseInt(v) < 10,
      checkUrl: async () => await fetch(),
    }
  })}
/>
```

So here how can i show different messages for each validation.

like number is -5, then i show

```
"Number is not positive"
"Number less than 10"
```

HOw to access each error `positive` and `lessThanTen`

Comment: You can just return a string from the validation function: `positive: v => parseInt(v) > 0 || "Number is not positive"`

Comment: How do make use of the keys. or loop and show them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per default RHF will only show one error per field, so if there are multiple you will you don't have to loop over them. You can just use the `errors` object provided by RHF and access the `name` of your field and then the `message` property.

If you need to have all errors to be shown simultaneously you can set the config `criteriaMode`, check the docs [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform) for more info.

```js
function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label htmlFor="test1">Test Field</label>
      <input
        {...register("test1", {
          validate: {
            positive: (v) => parseInt(v) > 0 || "Number is not positive",
            lessThanTen: (v) => parseInt(v) < 10 || "Number less than 10",
            checkUrl: async () => {
              const result = await Promise.resolve(true);

              return result || "result was false so show this message";
            }
          }
        })}
      />
      {errors.test1 && <p>{errors.test1.message}</p>}

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Custom validation (forked)]

Comment: i can access each error using `type`

Answer (score 0):

To apply multiple validations, you can build a custom hook as a resolver. A custom hook can easily integrate with yup/Joi/Superstruct as a validation method, and be used inside validation resolver.

You can find more doc and examples here:
https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/
in the section:
Custom Hook with Resolver

I recommend you `yup`.

Comment: my question is more specific to `validate` key